# Jaspersoft server excel export cell height increases

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel, jasperserver

I've designed the report in Jaspersoft (5.6.1). When I upload it to server and export to excel, the cell height changes according to the next cell item.

Assume there is text field of height 0.20 inches and next to it is a Chart of Height 5.20 Inches. When I export this design from studio, it works fine. But when I export to excel from JasperServer, the Text field cell height increases according to height of Chart.

I'm sure I kept each field's  position type to Fix realtive to Top and Strech type to No strech.

Is there any special settings to be done on Server side too?

FYI, I followed all tips for Excel export

Thanks

Sreeram

Comment: You should post screenshots (to illustrate problem) and small *jrxml* to reproduce the issue

Comment: Try to set the collapseRowSpan property of the xlsExportParameters bean in WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml to false.  Restarting the server is required.

Comment: Hi,Could you advise which node of the xml do I need to add net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.collapse.row.span=false? As there are different nodes compared to /webapps/jasperserver-pro/WEB-INF/classes/jasperreports.properties

Comment: I found the node where it has to be added. I've added and restarted the services but Jasper is not working at all. Please correct the code below

Comment: `<bean id="xlsExportParameters" class="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.common.XlsExportParametersBean">
    <property name="collapseRowSpan" value="false"/>
  </bean>`